# Finding a constant so that is an martingale

Tags: probability

Let $X_i$ be IID with $P(X_i=1)=\frac{2}{3}$ and $P(X_i=-1)=\frac{1}{3}$. Define $S_n = \sum_{n} X_i$. Find the constant $c \neq 1$ so that $c^{S_n}$ is a martingale. 
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E(c^{S_{n+1}}|\mathcal F_n)=c^{S_n} E(c^{X_{n+1}})$ so martingale property holds iff $E(c^{X_{n+1}})=1$ or $c\frac 2 3 +\frac 1 c \frac 1 3=1$. This is a quadratic equation . Can you solve this for $c$?.

Comment: Can you explain how you get that equation for $c$?

Comment: $Ec^{X_{n+1}}=c^{1}P(X_{N+1}=1)+c^{-1}P(X_{N+1}=-1)=c\frac 2 3 +\frac  1 c \frac 1 3$.

Comment: Thank you, i got it